# Неописуема / не описуема ни словом, / Ни пером, ни мыслей

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Не каждый

Наизготове быть готов,

Признаюсь честно,

К провалам,

Численность которых

**Неописуема / не описуема** ни словом,

Ни пером, ни мыслей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя правилами будет скорее рекомендовано **слитное** написание, можно допустить и **раздельную** форму письма:

```
Не каждый
Наизготове быть готов,
Признаюсь честно,
К провалам,
Численность которых
не описуема ни словом,
Ни пером, ни мыслями.
```

**Пояснение**

1. В языке существует ряд прилагательных,  имеющих форму причастий настоящего времени: ***образуемый, испытуемый, рисуемый***. Они не всегда указаны в словаре, но на практике применяются, хотя и не часто.

Аналогичная ситуация со словом ***описуемый.*** Это слово подчёркивает  орфографический редактор,  и оно встречается редко, в то время как  вариант ***неописуемый*** весьма частотный, см. **[Карта слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9).**

Из этого можно бы сделать вывод, что даже при наличии **усилительных** слов  или **зависимых слов в Т.п.** написание  должно быть слитным, сравнить: **никем непобедимая** (нет слова победимый).

2. Но прилагательное ***непобедимый*** образовано от глагола **совершенного** вида, в то время как ***описуемый*** можно соотнести  с глаголом **несовершенного** вида ***описывать***, как и рисовать — ***рисуемый***, испытывать — ***испытуемый***.
3. Поэтому нет прямого запрета на прилагательное ***описуемый***, оно просто нечастотное, как и другие подобные слова.

**Примеры**

1. Родион Щедрин (2002). Реакция была, вообще говоря, **трудно описуемая.**
2. Н. Б. Черных (2015) Болезни, угасание, какая-то особенная и **мало описуемая** неряшливость во всём.
3. Александр Гаррос(2001). Мичман сгорбился, не пытаясь сопротивляться, в метнувшемся снизу на Вадима взгляде мгновенно сменились просто очень сильная боль, беспредельная, фундаментальная, **никакими словами не описуемая** дезориентация и сразу же — нарастающий, перерастающий в панику испуг.